# How To Loop Through Set Of Value Pairs JSON Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

im trying to loop through  a JSON object via Jquery. For some reason its not looping right.. It seems to be looping all the way to the end, But I would like to get each individually property in my object. Im using a For(var in) loop which loops through my object correctly but its a bit off.. MyAny help would be glady appreciated.. thanks so much!!! I can provide a quick link to my website that has mock up of the code if needed..
Ive also added more code and html via elements that using ..Hint*** Theres more if - conditional statements that checks for sounds_like,sounds_price...    The first JSON Object works with no problem, its the second JSON object that im using with the pop over thats causing me trouble

```
    <div class="overlay-bg">
         <div id= "overlay" class="overlay-content">
             <p>This is a popup!</p>
          <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>


        $.getJSON("php/music_data.php",function(data){
             $.each(data,function(key,obj){

                 for(var prop in obj){
                     // console.log("Property: " + prop + " key:" + obj[prop]);
                     if(prop === "sounds_like"){

                         results_div =  document.getElementById("results");
                         music_div_container = document.createElement("div");
                         music_div_container.id  = "music_data_container";
                         music_div_container.innerHTML = "<div id=\"sounds_like\">" + "Sounds Like: "  + obj["sounds_like"] +"</div>";
                         results_div.appendChild(music_div_container);

                         var pop_up = document.createElement("a");
                         pop_up.href = "#";
                         pop_up.className = "show-popup";
                         pop_up.innerHTML = "Click";
                         music_div_container.appendChild(pop_up);

                         default_photo = document.createElement('div');


                     }

                     if(prop === "sound_desc"){

                         var sound_desc = document.createElement("div");
                         sound_desc.innerHTML  = "<div id=\"sounds_desc\">" +        obj["sound_desc"] +"</div>";
                         music_div_container.appendChild(sound_desc);

                     }


     $.getJSON("php/music_data.php",function(data){
   $.each(data,function(idx,obj){

    $.each(obj,function(key,value){

        $(".show-popup").click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();     
            $(".overlay-bg").show();

              if(key === "sounds_like"){
                          /***Should be Beyonce,Drake,Nicki Minaj***/
                          /*****But my console is showing Nicki Minaj*******/
                  $(".overlay-content").html(value);
              }
            if(value === "sounds_desc"){
                           /***Should be Smooth, Wu tang Forever, Barbie***/
                          /*****But my console is showing Barbie*******/
                $(".overlay-content").html(value);
             }


            $('.close-btn').click(function(){
                $('.overlay-bg').hide(); /*** hide the overlay ***/
            });

            $('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
                $('.overlay-bg').hide(); 
            });

            $('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
                return false;
            })
        });
    });

   })
 });
```

JSON Object Below

```
[{"id":"39","sounds_like":"Beyonce","sound_name":"Dance 4 u.mp3","sound_desc":"Smooth","sound_genre":"R&B","sound_price":"N/A","photo_path":"\/admin_data\/uploaded_artist_photos\/","photo_name":"beyonce.jpg"},
 {"id":"40","sounds_like":"Drake","sound_name":"Bottom.mp3","sound_desc":"Wu Tang Forever","sound_genre":"Rap","sound_price":"N/A","photo_path":"\/admin_data\/uploaded_artist_photos\/","photo_name":"drake.jpg"},
 {"id":"41","sounds_like":"Nicki Minaj","sound_name":"RomanReloaded.mp3","sound_desc":"Barbie","sound_genre":"Rap","sound_price":"N/A","photo_path":"\/admin_data\/uploaded_artist_photos\/","photo_name":"nickiminaj.jpg"}
]
```

Comment: Why are you adding a new click handler for each iteration?

Comment: try to convert json to javascript object using jquery's `parseJSON()` then iterate over the created object  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @ Slaks, im adding a click handler because for each element that has a event, my pop up is showing or its hiding its background via the selectors ('.close-btn'),('overlay-bg'), and ('.overlay-bg'), all ave handlers attach to them.. but I dont think thats the cause for my loop not looping correctly..

Comment: Your code logic doesn't make sense.  The second `$.each()` will be iterating each property of an object in the array and you will be installing a click handler on `.show-popup` for each property of each object.  I really doubt that is what you want.  That means you'll be installed 24 click handlers on exactly the same object.

Comment: @RicoPlasakoi: Those selectors will apply for *all* elements in the *whole page*, not only for each item separately. On every single click on a popup you are going to attach masses of event listeners to the DOM.

Comment: @jfriend  && Bergi ...So removing the second $.each() should eliminate multiple click handlers from attaching to the DOM... Thanks so much

Comment: You will have to describe what you're really trying to accomplish.  The event handlers probably need to be removed from both loops.  I was going to show you how to do that, but I don't understand what you're really trying to do.  We may need to see the relevant HTML also.

Comment: @ Ok, i have insert my html that im using for this code, in a snapshot i have other code thats creating elements dynamically(divs,images) and when a user clicks on each element, i want the pop up to show what each element has pulled from my JSON object such as.. (sound_desc,sounds_like).... I've got my other elements to render and show my JSON objects correctly but when looping to show my JSON Data within the pop over its acting a bit weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop a complex object using a for var in loop, you will always have unexpected behaviors because of how this loop works.

To avoid such problems and if you need to use this type of loop, I recommend you do the following:

Example:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {  // this validates if prop belongs to obj 
        // do something
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but using jquery you can do the following:

```
$.getJSON("php/music_data.php", function (data) {

    $.each(data, function (i, value) {
        //alert(i + ": " + value.id);

        alert(value.sounds_like); 
        // this will have Beyonce , Drake, Nicki Minaj

    });

});
```

Another thing that does not seem right is that you're doing bind click event on each loop. Is it better to do this differently.

Comment: But the OP's isn't using a `for` loop for looping.  They're using jQuery iteration.  So, there's no reason to switch to this.

Comment: @ Sandcar , ive tried this numerous times, still my properties arent showing correctly..

Comment: @ Scandcar looping over each object the way you describe worked!! Thanks

Comment: @ Rico Plasakoi glad I could helped!